# Dynamic width size to fit of controls in stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, xcode10

I have a horizontal stackview with button and label

Case 1:
Button text is dynamic and size of it should fit to text. So I added hugging and compression to required. This works perfectly

Case 2:
But when my label is hidden, Button takes entire space of stackview. How can i avoid that?

I need my button width fixed to fit the title. Please refer below screen how it looks

**ALL Constraints are added in storyboard. I don't want to do it programatically**

[image]

Please advice

Comment: That's normal `UIStackView` behaviour. You could set the label's `alpha` to **0** instead of setting its `isHidden` property to `true`. Or set the label's `text` to an empty string.

Comment: You can add width constraint to button

Comment: Or just use `UIView` instead of `UIStackView`

Comment: add a fixed width to button and a 750 priority trailing on the stackview to superview

Comment: Don't use trailing constant for the UIStackView then it will automatically adjust width as per the content.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways for that.

[image]

**First stackView:** Your normal case.

**Second stackView:**

- The label.text has " " value.
- Adding a blank text could make the stackView height increase if you don't explicitly add a height constraint for the stackView.
- Also, the button has a width constraint.

**Third stackView:**

- The label alpha is set to 0.
- The button has a width constraint.